# Change icon on click function

Tags: jquery, html

I createad a toggle button and I put a arrow in it, but I want that when the button it's clicked, the arrow changes. I'm using font awesome to put this arrows, so I just have to change fa-chevron-right to fa-chevron-down on click.

I tried this but it's not working.

```
 <button class="btn btn-warning btn-receita offset-lg-2" id="btn-receitamob" data-clicked-times="0"> CLIQUE AQUI PARA VER A RECEITA <span id="span-circle"> <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" id="seta"></i> </span>                      </button>

<div id="receita-div" style="display: none;" class="receita-hidden">
--content




<script> 
    $( "#btn-receitamob" ).click(function() {
        $("#receita-div").slideToggle(1500);
    });
</script> 
<script>
    $("#btn-receitamob").click(function() {
        $('.fa-chevron-right').removeClass(".fa-chevron-right").addClass(".fa-chevron-down"); //Adds 'a', removes 'b'

    }, function() {
        $('.fa-chevron-right').removeClass(".fa-chevron-down").addClass(".fa-chevron-right"); //Adds 'b', removes 'a'

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your HTML?

Comment: Are you getting any `console` errors? Also it should have been `removeClass('fa-chaveron-down')` and `addClass('fa-cheveon-right')`.. No prepending **dot (.)**

Comment: See a more explained answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45245525/3853133

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle font awesome class on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245301/toggle-font-awesome-class-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your [.slideToggle(1500)](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) means: the slide animation runs for 1 second and an half. Hence, you need to run your toggling class in the complete callback.

Your second click event handler cannot work because it is attached to the class that is going to disappear when toggling.

```js
$( "#btn-receitamob" ).click(function() {
  $("#receita-div").slideToggle(1500, function () {
      // 
      //  if you want to toogle at the eend of animation
      //
      //$("#btn-receitamob i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down");
  });
  
  //
  // if you want to toogle the icon right in time
  //
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">


<button class="btn btn-warning btn-receita offset-lg-2" id="btn-receitamob" data-clicked-times="0"> CLIQUE AQUI PARA VER
    A RECEITA <span id="span-circle"> <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" id="seta"></i> </span></button>

<div id="receita-div" style="display: none;" class="receita-hidden">
    --content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to have a common class and toggle its right and down class. Something like below:

For example, I will add `icon` class to the element which has `fa-cheveron-right` element.
Then I will access it like below:

```
<script> 
    $( "#btn-receitamob" ).click(function() {
        $("#receita-div").slideToggle(1500);
        $(this).find(".icon").toggleClass('fa-cheveron-right fa-chevron-down');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Gururasad Rao said, remove dot on class names "fa-chaveron-down" and "fa-chaveron-right"