# Button underline animation with css and html

Tags: html, css, animation

I have two buttons that have underline animation when I click them. What I want to achieve is that one button, after being clicked, stays underlined, and, if I click the other one, the first removes the underlining and the other becomes underlined.

A problem is also that when I release the mouse, the underlining fades out. I don't know how to do it. Here is the code I have for now:

HTML:

```
<div id = 'hey'>
  <div class = 'b' id = 'b1' href="#">Button one</div>
    <div class = 'b' id = 'b2' href="#">Button Two</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html { 
  font: bold 14px/1.4 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}
#hey { 
  margin: 150px auto 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  list-style: none; 
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}

.b {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;

  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.b:after {    
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}
.b:active:after { 
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
}
```

Comment: If jQuery would be useful I will be happy to use it

Comment: You can actually solve this with pure CSS by using checkbox and CSS sibling selector. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001709/5526624

Comment: Also, you don't need JQuery for this thing. It's simple enough with vanilla JS, but now you already selected the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to use jQuery:

```
$('#hey').find('.b').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $('#hey').find('.b').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('active');});
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Then just use the class `active` for the underlining.

Comment: I will try it out! I also thought about jQuery :)

Comment: I tried on jsFiddle and local webstorm instance and does not work on both...

Comment: Yes, for some reason when I pasted your code it did not... Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

Please include jquery cdn link then

Try this script

```
$(".b").click(function() {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('#hey').find('.b').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('active');});
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
  else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

Aldo add this css

```
.b.active:after { 
   width: 100%; 
   left: 0; 
}
```

[Working fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/2k108osw/)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#hey .b').click(function(){
 $('#hey .b').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
});
```

```css
body,html { 
  font: bold 14px/1.4 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}
#hey { 
  margin: 150px auto 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  list-style: none; 
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
}

#hey .b {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#hey .b:after {    
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}
#hey .b.active:after { 
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div id = 'hey'>
  <div class="active b" id = 'b1' href="#">Button one</div>
  <div class="b" id = 'b2' href="#">Button Two</div>
</div>
```